# Java Type casting char to int

Tags: integer, char

If we want to type cast char to int data type, as per the type casting rule, there should be a relationship between the char and int data type to compile the program right?

for example,
char r = 'a';
int a = int(r);

here there should be parent to child or chile to parent or same type relationship should be there right. what is the relationship here between char and int?

Answer (score 0):

Requiring a relationship between the types only applies to reference types, those which inherit from `Object`. `char` and `int` are primitive types, casting between them only uses their actual value. Same applies for casting to/from `long` or `double`, for example.

Comment: can you pl explain in different way? kind of confusing.

Comment: oK. type casting for primitive types do not have such relationship concepts?

Comment: @shivu2012 correct, primitive types only use the inherent value when casting